# Keep variable shared among requests

Tags: php

Is there any way to keep the result of some long calculation shared among all requests?

For example in Ruby on Rails, everything that is keep in the config/initializers directory is run once when the server is booted. Then if one of the initializers change, the whole server has to be restarted. While this causes some undesiderable things, like editing some configuration and not seeing changes until you realize that you have to restart the whole thing, I can also see some use cases, for example for route mapping. Filling the whole route map array on each request might consume, at some point, a noticeable part of the server time.

Instead I would fill the array on server boot and keep that alive until shutdown.
Is there any way of doing this in PHP (no $_SESSION please)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try a cache server like [Redis](http://redis.io/).

Comment: @Sam is right, you are describing caching.

Comment: @Sam is so rigtht, that if he answered instead of commenting I would have accepted it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to elaborate my comment into more of an answer, so that it is "worthy" of being accepted.  Since you don't want to use sessions (because its not user-specific), you need to store the information "somewhere".  You could technically do this in your typical relational database like MySQL or PostgreSQL, etc.  However, for the amount of information you are storing (minor config details, etc) and the amount of times this information is accessed (probably every request), it makes sense to store it in a cache database.  This will store all of your data in RAM, and you can set it to expire at a certain time, exist forever, or wipe it on a system reboot.

Some examples of cache:

- [Redis](http://redis.io/)
- [memcached](http://memcached.org/)
- [PHP's APC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php)